# How to check if edit text has drawable

Tags: android

I'm using SpannableStringBuilder to add an image in my edit text. But my problem is how can I detect if the edit text still contains image or not? i.e, I have an edit text that has both image and text then I remove the image and leave the text only. Now I want to check if my edit text still has the image.

I'm using this codes to add text to my edit text.

```
final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),options);
getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap, Color.BLUE,2,2,context);
String prevText = composeMessage.getText().toString();
SpannableStringBuilder ss = new SpannableStringBuilder(" \n" + prevText); 
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mmsPhoto, 120, 120, false)));

d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight()); 
ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE); 
ss.setSpan(span, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
composeMessage.setText(ss);
```

Comment: ss.getSpans() is your friend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following method:

```
public boolean hasImageSpan(EditText editText) {
    Editable text  = editText.getEditableText();
    ImageSpan[] spans = text.getSpans(0, text.length(), ImageSpan.class);
    return !(spans.length == 0);
}
```

Comment: how can I toast or log the return of this method?

Comment: You can do something like: `Log.i("SPAN", "Has Drawable?:" + hasImageSpan(composeMessage))`

Comment: Basically, get all image spans in the `composeMessage` and see if `length==0`. `0` means no image inside..